# Printing jRadioButtons in jTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jradiobutton, listen

I am having trouble figuring out how to add jRadioButton selections into my program. I am not sure if I am supposed to make a listener method or what because I have never created a listener and am a little confused on how to do so.

My code is as follows:

```
    package my.userFormUI;
/**
 *
 * @author Randy
 */

import java.awt.event.*;
public class userFormUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    //Register a listener for the radio buttons.



    /**
     * Creates new form userFormUI
     */
    public userFormUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    int age;
    int year;
    String studying;

    public int getAge(int year_of_birth){//get year method
        age = 2014 - year_of_birth;
    return age;
}//end method

    public void printTextField(String text) {
    jTextArea1.setText(text);
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jDialog1 = new javax.swing.JDialog();
        jDialog2 = new javax.swing.JDialog();
        jDialog3 = new javax.swing.JDialog();
        buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        name = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        year_of_birth = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jDialog1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jDialog1.getContentPane());
        jDialog1.getContentPane().setLayout(jDialog1Layout);
        jDialog1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jDialog1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jDialog2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jDialog2.getContentPane());
        jDialog2.getContentPane().setLayout(jDialog2Layout);
        jDialog2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jDialog2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jDialog2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jDialog2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jDialog3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jDialog3.getContentPane());
        jDialog3.getContentPane().setLayout(jDialog3Layout);
        jDialog3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jDialog3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jDialog3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jDialog3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "User Information", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12), new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0))); // NOI18N

        jLabel1.setText("NAME:");

        jLabel2.setText("YEAR BORN:");

        jLabel3.setText("EMPLOYMENT STATUS:");

        name.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                nameActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        year_of_birth.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                year_of_birthActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Employed", "Not Employed" }));
        jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setText("STUDYING");

        jRadioButton1.setText("Yes");
        jRadioButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jRadioButton2.setText("No");
        jRadioButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jRadioButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(year_of_birth))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                                .addComponent(name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 277, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jRadioButton2))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 227, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addGap(0, 26, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(year_of_birth, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(14, 14, 14)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton2))
                .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jButton1.setText("SUBMIT");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jButton2.setText("EXIT");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 121, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void year_of_birthActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:              

    }                                             


    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here 
        String employment = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        printTextField("Welcome " + name.getText() + "! You are " + getAge(Integer.parseInt(year_of_birth.getText())) + 
                " old." + "\n" + "Your Employment Status: " + employment + 
                "\n" + "Your Studying Status: " + studying);


    }                                        

    private void nameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                    

    private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.exit(0);
    }                                        

    private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

        jRadioButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
    studying = "Not Studying";
    }
 });

    }                                             

    private void jRadioButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        jRadioButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
    studying = "Studying";
    }
});
    }                                             

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(userFormUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(userFormUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(userFormUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(userFormUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new userFormUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JDialog jDialog1;
    private javax.swing.JDialog jDialog2;
    private javax.swing.JDialog jDialog3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField name;
    private javax.swing.JTextField year_of_birth;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

As you can see I have made a listener but all I get is a null result for my studying variable. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve and what isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already added `ActionListener` to the radio buttons

```
    jRadioButton1.setText("Yes");
    jRadioButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jRadioButton2.setText("No");
    jRadioButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jRadioButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
```

Now you need to add what you want to be performed in the `ActionPerformed` methods rather than adding a new ActionListeners!

```
private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    studying = "Not Studying";
}                                             

private void jRadioButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    studying = "Studying";
}
```

And to manages the selected/unselected state of the two radio buttons so the two buttons can't be selected at the same time, add these two line on the constructor after `initComponenets` method

```
buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton1);
buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton2);
```

--

Note: I recommend to use `ItemListener` rather than `ActionListener` with `JRadioButton`

Comment: I changed it and I get a bunch of errors, one is class, interface, or enum expected.

Comment: Hey sorry, I figured out what you meant. I inputted that code wrong the first time. However, when I run the program no matter what I pick for a answer for studying it says "Yes".

Comment: This is your code after edit and it's show the result as you want without any problem, check it http://pastie.org/9408144